# why zip returns only two items (Python 3)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip

I'm having problems understanding what happens here.

```
networkfile="http://regulondb.ccg.unam.mx/menu/download/datasets/files/network_tf_gene.txt"

i = 36

lista = []

for n in range(0,8):

    data = urllib.request.urlopen(networkfile).readlines()[i]
    line = data.decode('utf-8')
    line2 = line[0:5]
    lista.append(line2)
    i = i + 1

print(lista)

values = []

for i in range(0,8):

    values.append('')

print(values)

d = dict(zip(lista,values))

print(d)
```

I know this is far from the most efficient way to deal with this type of problem, but I'm pretty new to this so for now this'll have to do.

My problem is that the output looks like:

```
'AccB\t', 'AccB\t', 'AcrR\t', 'AcrR\t', 'AcrR\t', 'AcrR\t', 'AcrR\t', 'AcrR\t']

['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

{'AccB\t': '', 'AcrR\t': ''}
```

The first two lists work properly, as implied by the print-command, but as soon as i zip those two lists, and create a dictionary of them, the dictionary contains only two elements from each list, and I have no idea why this is even after I've tried to find out for some hours.

Any other tips & improvement suggestions are very much appreciated as well. Thanks.

Comment: Add  your sample output

Answer (score 0):

I suggest breaking up your code into logical steps, rather than doing multiple steps in the same line.  Then you'll see that `zip` isn't giving you two items, it's `dict`.

```
lista = ['AccB\t', 'AccB\t', 'AcrR\t', 'AcrR\t', 'AcrR\t', 'AcrR\t', 'AcrR\t', 'AcrR\t']
values = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
>>> list(zip(lista, values))
[('AccB\t', ''), ('AccB\t', ''), ('AcrR\t', ''), ('AcrR\t', ''), ('AcrR\t', ''), ('AcrR\t', ''), ('AcrR\t', ''), ('AcrR\t', '')]
```

So you see, you're getting all the values expected.  But when you put this into a dictionary, you have many identical keys, so they get overwritten.  A dictionary can gave only one of each key.

```
>>> dict(_)
{'AcrR\t': '', 'AccB\t': ''}
```

`'AcrR\t'` and `'AccB\t'` were the only two keys, so in the dictionary, each will show up once.